# Azure Powershell - iterate through a list (txt) with db names and set them as variables in script

Tags: azure, powershell, loops, t-sql

I have the following challenge at the Moment:

With T-SQL I created a list of databases attached to our SQL instance and put this list in a txt file, so far no Problem.

Now with PowerShell I want to set up LongTermRetention backups in Azure with following cmdlet:

```
Set-AzSqlDatabaseBackupLongTermRetentionPolicy -ServerName $serverName -DatabaseName [name of database] -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -WeeklyRetention P53W -MonthlyRetention P48M -YearlyRetention P10Y -WeekOfYear 52
```

(I checked the Syntax of the cmdlet by inserting a database name manually and it works)

the variables given are set prior `(ServerName, resourceGroup)`

Where I am struggling now is, how I can get the names of the txt file one after another as parameter "DatabaseName" into my cmdlet, as I have never done something like this.

I would be very grateful for either a link on how to do this or maybe a solution posted here.

Thank you in advance and Kind regards

**EDIT: I found a solution, Maybe not the most elegant, but working:
$files = Get-Content "C:\DEV\testfile.txt"
foreach ($file in $files){
Set-AzSqlDatabaseBackupLongTermRetentionPolicy -ServerName $serverName -DatabaseName $file -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -WeeklyRetention P53W -MonthlyRetention P48M -YearlyRetention P10Y -WeekOfYear 52
}**

I haven't thought it might have been that easy.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, mdie. Please, consider adding your solution as a answer and accepting it. It will help other people with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a flat text file where your database names are present like this:

```
server1
server2
server3
......
```

You can use the `Get-Content` cmdlet to read the file and iterate over each line using the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet. You can access the current item using `$_` ($_ represents the current value in the pipeline):

```
Get-Content -Path 'pathToYourFile.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    Set-AzSqlDatabaseBackupLongTermRetentionPolicy `
        -ServerName $_ `
        -DatabaseName [name of database] `
        -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
        -WeeklyRetention P53W `
        -MonthlyRetention P48M `
        -YearlyRetention P10Y `
        -WeekOfYear 52
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin Brandl, thank you that was exactly what I found out Right now. Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it very much!